# Executing Code behind before Xaml Rendering - How to influence the sequence

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, xaml

I'm working on a Windows Phone App.
I have a very performance intensive method which takes several seconds until the operation is done.

When the method is called I want to show an animated loading symbol which is defined in the xaml of my view. When the operation is finished it should disappear. I set the loading symbol to visible in the first line of this method.In the last line I set the visibility to collapsed.

The problem is that at first the whole code behind will be executed. Unfortunately nothing is to be seen, because the  the visibiliy is set to visible after the code behind operations are executed and in the same moment its set to collapsed.

Has anybody an idea how to solve this problem? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that you're calling your method on the main (UI) thread.  This means that your method blocks the UI from refreshing, and also means that (as you noted) by the time the UI *does* refresh, you've already hidden the icon again.

What you need to do instead is call your method on a background thread (there are a number of ways to handle this).  You will need to push the UI update to the UI thread (using `Dispatcher.Invoke`), but the rest of your method will run on a separate thread.

You'll also need to use a callback of some kind - maybe a custom event - so that your UI thread knows when the background thread is completed.

Comment: In addition to the Dan's explanation, I'd say that the C# 5 async/await pattern comes in aid for those situations. Here is a link about the Windows Store APIs, but the concepts are the same for WPF and the old-Phones. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(VS.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing the code its hard to say for sure but if you use the dispatcher to run you intensive code after the busy indicator is set this would allow the ui thread time to change before running the code.

An example

```
//This assumes you are binding in xaml to the isbusy and it implements INotifyPropertyChanged
IsBusy = true;
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>{ //...performance intense here
});
```

That being Said Dan Puzey is right. You should only run this logic on the UI thread if for some reason your need to. even then be wary of this as it makes for a poor ui experience.

One way you could accomplish this and still have your dispatcher fire off when you need would be to pass a copy of the dispatcher into the background.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (d => {
    //...performance intense here
    Dispatcher dispatcher = d as Dispatcher;
    if(dispatcher != null){
         dispatcher.BeginInvoke()()=>{//...ui updates here }
    }

}, Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);//make sure this is called from your UI thread or you may not end up with the correct dispatcher
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the fast response.

Now I implement:

 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { LoadProject(); });

The loading symbol is now visible for the time of loading, but it is frozen (dos not do the animation).

I have to read how to use the busyIndicator now. But I guess its a WPF specific thing, not available for silverlight Windows Phone. I  will see.

Thanks for the good hints in the right direction :)

Comment: All this does is ensure that the current method completes before the hard work is done *explicitly on the UI thread*, which is why the animation doesn't run.  *Don't* run your performance intense stuff with the `Dispatcher`, run it in a background thread